# Object service in multiple components *ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following object in a service. How can I use it in multiple components? I want to call them with `*ngFor` to use them. Or in any case what is the correct way to do it ?.

**data-paquetes.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataPaquetesService {

 paquetes: Array<object>;
 
 constructor() {

  this.paquetes = [
   { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 01', precio: '100' },
   { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 02', precio: '200' },
   { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 03', precio: '300' },
   { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 04', precio: '400' },
   { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 05', precio: '500' },
   { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 06', precio: '600' },
   { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 07', precio: '700' }

  ]
 }

}
```

**component-A.html**

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" *ngFor = "let paquete of paquetes">{{ paquete.nombre }} / {{ paquete.precio | currency}}</a>
```

**component-B.html**

```html
<option *ngFor = "let paquete of paquetes">{{ paquete.nombre}} / {{ paquete.precio | currency}}</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataPaquetesService {

paquetes: Array<object>;

constructor() {

    this.paquetes = [
        { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 01', precio: '100' },
        { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 02', precio: '200' },
        { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 03', precio: '300' },
        { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 04', precio: '400' },
        { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 05', precio: '500' },
        { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 06', precio: '600' },
        { nombre: 'Nombre paquete 07', precio: '700' }

    ]
}
getPaquetes() {
   return this.paquetes;
 }
}
```

and inside your componentA.ts

```
  import {MyService} from '...';
  export class ComponentA {
   paquetes= [];

   constructor(private myService: MyService){}
   }
   this.paquetes = this.myService.getPaquets();
```

inside your componentB.ts

```
  import {MyService} from '...';
  export class ComponentB {
    paquetes= [];
   constructor(private myService: MyService){}
   }
   this.paquetes= this.myService.getPaquets();
```

Comment: Thanks, in component A ts I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPaquetes' of undefined` Any idea?

Comment: check if the name of the service is correct in your constructor please

Comment: In the componentA.ts: `import { DataPaquetesService } from '../data-paquetes/data-paquetes.service';` then in the constructor: `constructor(private DataPaquetesService:DataPaquetesService) { }` Any idea?

Comment: constructor(private dataPaquetesService:DataPaquetesService) { } this.dataPaquetesService.getPaquetes();

Comment: I solved it in the following way: replaced by `this.paquetes = this.dataPaquetesService.getPaquetes();` by `paquetes = this.dataPaquetesService.getPaquetes();` I eliminated the `this`

Comment: you can make a decalaration paquetes = [] and after use this.paquetes, i will updated the answer

Comment: Excellent!. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if it was helpful please check the answer as correct